# Return the number of rows with a where condition after an INSERT INTO? postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that regroups some users and which event (as in IRL event) they've joined.

I have set up a server query that lets a user join an event.

It goes like this :

```
INSERT INTO participations
VALUES(:usr,:event_id)
```

I want that statement to also return the number of people who have joined the same event as the user. How do I proceed? If possible in one SQL statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common table expression like this to execute it as one query.

```
with insert_tbl_statement as  (

    insert into tbl values (4, 1) returning event_id
)
select (count(*) + 1) as event_count from tbl where event_id = (select event_id from insert_tbl_statement);
```

see demo http://rextester.com/BUF16406

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function, I've set up next example, but keep in mind you must add 1 to the final count because still transaction hasn't been committed.

> ```
> create table tbl(id int, event_id int);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into tbl values (1, 2),(2, 2),(3, 3);
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> create function new_tbl(id int, event_id int)
> returns bigint as $$
>
>     insert into tbl values ($1, $2);
>
>     select count(*) + 1 from tbl where event_id = $2;
>
> $$ language sql;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select new_tbl(4, 2);
> ```
>
> ```
> | new_tbl |
> | ------: |
> |       4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=14800d911aaf9398d74ea0ee637d18db)*

Comment: that would work, but it requires 2 queries if i'm correct? ( first you insert, then you select count ... ) i'd like to do it in 1 query, is it possible though?